# Referencing browserify bundle not working on Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I cannot reference my bundle script generated from browserify in my cordova app. It works when i tried running the app on browser. But i cannot seem to get it to run on android.

notify.js

```
global.send_notification = function (){
    var gcm = require('node-gcm');
    var message = new gcm.Message();
    //API Server Key
    var sender = new gcm.Sender('[API KEY]');
    var registrationIds = [];

    // Value the payload data to send...
    message.addData('message',"\u270C This is a test push from Everything Under \u2764 from PhoneGap \u2706!");
    message.addData('title','TEST OFFER!' );
    message.addData('msgcnt','3'); // Shows up in the notification in the status bar
    //message.addData('soundname','beep.wav'); //Sound to play upon notification receipt - put in the www folder in app
    //message.collapseKey = 'demo';
    //message.delayWhileIdle = true; //Default is false
    message.timeToLive = 3000;// Duration in seconds to hold in GCM and retry before timing out. Default 4 weeks (2,419,200 seconds) if not specified.

    // At least one reg id required
    registrationIds.push(regId);

    /**
     * Parameters: message-literal, registrationIds-array, No. of retries, callback-function
     */
    sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }); 
}
```

After browserify, running the following command in terminal:

```
browserify www/js/notify.js -o www/js/bundle_notify.js
```

I referenced **bundle_notify.js** in my main.html file before my main js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle_notify.js"></script>
```

Nothing happens when i call send_notification();

It works on perfectly on browser, however, it doesn't seem to work when i try building it on my android device.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution @Lawrence ? me too have a browserified bundle which is OK in laptop, but undefined module when trying to call it in cordova.